# Angular service injection design-pattern with two services closely related

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-services

I have two service such as `Service1` and `Service2`.

Both services are registered in `AppModule`(**Root** module).

`Service2` is injected to `Service1` like the below.

```
@Injectable()
class Service2{
  constructor(){}
  public foo(){}
}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
class Service1{
  constructor(public service2:Service2){
    this.service2.foo()
  }
}
```

And, a component needs `Service1` and function **foo()** of `Service2`.

In this point, I have a question about **design-pattern injecting those services to components**. I think there are two ways to achieve my goal.

**Pattern 1**

```
@Component()
class Component{
  constructor(
    public service1:Service1
    ,public service2:Service2
  ){
    this.service2.foo()
  }
}
```

**Pattern 2**

```
@Component()
class Component{
  constructor(
    public service1:Service1
  ){
    this.service1.service2.foo()
  }
}
```

I think **Pattern 2** is better because of **simplicity**.

So, which one is better? Or is there Any other Suggestion?

Comment: does service1 need service2?

Comment: Its personal preference but pattern 1 is the better approach because it already has access to service 2.

Comment: @fateme fazli Yes, `Service1` needs `Service2`.

Answer (score 0):

Observe your Pattern 2, you have to `this.service1.service2.foo()` every time you have to use it, for me its extra work. In both patterns your Service is initialized so I'll suggest Pattern 1, as `this.service2.foo()` is much efficient.